# sed substitution works in terminal but not in SAS pipe

Tags: regex, sed, sas, pipe, solaris

If I run the command `echo abc | sed 's/b/\'$'\n'/` at a terminal, I get the output:

```
a
c
```

But if run the following SAS code on on the same server, reading the output of exactly the same command,

```
filename cmd pipe "echo abc | sed 's/b/\'$'\n'/";
data _null_;
  infile cmd;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

I get this in the log instead:

```
a$nc
```

How can I make the SAS pipe output match what I get in the terminal?

**Further details**

I'm using SAS 9.1.3 on Solaris 10 / SunOS 5.1. The Solaris version of sed I'm using does not support \n escape sequences for newlines in regexes, hence the shell substitution in the command above. If I run

```
echo abc | sed s/b/\n/
```

I get the following output (in a terminal):

```
anc
```

I do not have the option of using any other version of sed.

I already have a `tr`-based solution, but I would like to find a way of making this work in sed if possible, so that I can replace longer strings with newlines.

Comment: That works! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: another thing is, solaris toolkit sucks. their functionality is half of the gnu one. to use gnu toolkit in solaris, go `/usr/gnu/bin` and with the binary name.

Comment: glad that worked. i've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't know about SAS, but the problem could be quite universal in various languages, which is: languages fork commands without a shell, therefore your pipe is not recognized. you need to change your code into `bash -c "echo abc | sed 's/b/\'$'\n'/"`. you need to deal with quotes, of course.

Comment: `/usr/gnu/bin: No such file or directory`, unfortunately

Comment: @user667489 oh. so your solaris doesn't have `gnu` install. i don't exactly know how your environment is constructed but if you are interested in installing gnu tools in your solaris, try this: https://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/getting-started.html

Comment: Where is `/usr/gnu/bin` coming from?

Comment: @AndrewHenle A previously edited out part of the answer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it comes from a part that i suggested OP to use gnu toolkit following the second part of the question but it seems he doesn't have it installed so i delete that part from the answer since it does not apply to the question.